# Some example of query to google maps api inside of my own html

Tags: javascript, html, url, google-maps-api-3

I have html page (index) with google map (in div tags) in it. And my task is to get query data from the url for example `mysite.com/index?lat=44.333,lng=22.111` and it will display marker on the map, which coordinates will be (44.333;22,111).

And without query it will work as usual - clear init map, and so on. But when there will be that query it should initialize with that marker allready.

Comment: Why didn't you provide the code without asking us to ask you? Of course we need the code!

Comment: Are you having trouble implementing the marker infowindow?  If so, please show us your attempt and explain the problem you're having with your code.

Comment: Looking at your example url, you can succeed with the help of php.

Comment: I just don't know if you need it. Sure i can post it. It need's to be in file or some specific tags?

Comment: We only need to see the segment of code that demonstrates your attempt to implement the marker infowindow, and it should be included in your question (not a link).  Thanks.

Comment: I need not infowindow, what I need is so i can handle some query, like if you saw at google maps site. Like https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393   but so it works on my page, where are other things except map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the full url by using window.location.href, then parse the string using regex or string methods to isolate the latitude + longitude. Then once the map has loaded drop a marker using the lat + long you obtained from the link. This is all assuming you only need one marker placed on initial map load. To run an actual query against *your server* you need to be running a service on the server-side such as PHP and a database.